# Libgdx Box2d Drawing

Tags: libgdx, box2d, tiled

I'm trying to render an sprite with his body but it always displays bigger and moved to the left and bottom.

I'm using a OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer with an scale of 1/(PPM*3) where PPM is 100.

The tiles and the body i created gets drawn where i want them but i can't get the sprite to match the body.
The sprite is 70x70, same size as the tiles.

Debug render.
[image: Debug Render]

With the sprites on.
[image: Debug Render]

This is my render method on the sprite.

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(sprite,
          body.getPosition().x  * PPM - sprite.getWidth() / 2,
          body.getPosition().y  * PPM - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
batch.end();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to put the origin of sprite to center and see what happen : sprite.setOriginCenter()